# What does 0usize represent and why isn't it listed in the primitives?

Tags: rust, primitive

Rust [Primitives](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/primitives.html)

What does `0usize` represent?

Comment: The documentation should provide a link from Primatives to primative literals. Also that page.. https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/literals.html#literals - could do with some rework - The example detracts. The lines at the top convey enough. Makes it easier to scan. The whole size in bytes is a whole different concept that muddies waters. asserts would make more sense it is really necessary to deviate from the concept.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-by-example/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md